# How to split string using CRLF delimiter in cpp?

Tags: c++, split, newline, delimiter

I have some string :

```
testing testing

test2test2
```

these lines are devided by CRLF. I saw that there are : `0d0a0d0a` deviding them.
How can I split it using this information?

I wanted to use `str.find(CRLF-DELIMITER)` but can't semm to figure how

editing  :
I already used `str.find("textDelimiter")`, but now I need it to look for hexa and not search for a string `"0d0a0d0a"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `boost::split` to do that. Please also take a look at `Boost.Tokenizer`.

Here is another way of doing it using regex:

```
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using boost::algorithm::split_regex;

int main()
{
    vector<string> res;
    string input = "test1\r\ntest2\r\ntest3";
    split_regex(res, input, boost::regex("(\r\n)+"));
    for (auto& tok : res) 
    {
        std::cout << "Token: " << tok << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the way of doing it without Boost:

```
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <istream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
     std::string strlist("line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3\r\n");
     std::istringstream MyStream(strlist);
     std::vector<std::string> v;
     std::string s;
     while (std::getline(MyStream, s))
     {
        v.push_back(s);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I read about it, someone wrote that :Then you don't have boost installed. How can I install that?

Comment: I'm not the only one using this code, it means that if someone will rebase to my version - > it won't compile. Is there any other option to split it?

Comment: added way of doing it without boost per your request

Comment: std::getline does not split on CRLF, only LF.